# Fetch data from server to my application in j2me

Tags: java, java-me, client-server

I want to fetch data from server side to my application which is in j2me. The data to fetch from server is like sms, mms etc which are already stored in server.
Do I need to use XML parsing for this.
If yes the how can I use it? Please send me the code for it.
If no then what should I use and help me through code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use webservice to communicate between your server and your mobile client.

The design would be like

[image]

**Also See**

- [Introduction to J2ME Web Services](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/wsa/)
- [Understanding the Web Services Subset API for Java ME](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/webservices/)