# how to save data fetched from server using J2ME application

Tags: java-me

I want to fetch data from server side to my application which is in j2me. The data fetch from server is username and mobile no. which is already stored in server. In our project we have implemented the functionality of add, delete, view the contacts which are present on server. So now we have to implement the "Save" function so that all that server data (user name and mobile nos.) will get stored and displayed on that mobile emulator. Do I need to use XML parsing for this? If yes then how can I use it? If no then what should I use? Help me with code examples.

Comment: what have you tried so far? did you copy the question text from this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667245/fetch-data-from-server-to-my-application-in-j2me?

Comment: no..its not similar to earlier question.but if you have any suggestion for us,please reply.

Comment: @DhanaashreePanPatil, in either case at least check the link provided by `gnat` it has refer material that might be helpful.

Comment: @Vimal : Hey friend...its not at all imp for us.

Answer (score 1):

The steps would be to fetch the data from server using one of the webservices methodology and store it in the device. Each step below has the reference links

**FETCH DATA FROM SERVER**

*My Answer To Other Post*

[Designing a mobile web server and client for traffic compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318610/designing-a-mobile-web-server-and-client-for-traffic-compression/8390762#8390762)

*JSON*

1. [Using JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) in Java ME for Data
   Interchange](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javame/json-me/#2)
2. [RESTful Web Service Upload/Download Large Data With
   JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128361/restful-web-service-upload-download-large-data-with-json/8128497#8128497)

*XML*

1. [Add XML parsing to your J2ME
   applications](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wi-parsexml/#ibm-pcon)
2. [Parsing XML in
   J2ME](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/parsingxml/)

*SOAP*

1. [Determining methods available in a web service by examining the
   WSDL
   file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534124/determining-methods-available-in-a-web-service-by-examining-the-wsdl-file/7536679#7536679)

.

**STORE DATA IN DEVICE**

FileSystem

1. [Getting Started with the FileConnection
   APIs](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/fileconnection/)

RecordStore

1. [save data from servlet to recordstore in
   j2me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456893/save-data-from-servlet-to-recordstore-in-j2me/8457619#8457619)

Comment: @DhanaashreePanPatil Were you able to resolve your problem? If so mark and [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) that helped you.